# AWS RDS MySQL difference between free_data and Free Storage Space metric

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm struggling to find what consuming storage on MySQL RDS instance.

We have **30Gb** RDS instance

**Slow** and **general** logs are disabled;

**binlogs** removed immediately (better say as soon as possible)

Free Storage Space metric reports **~10Gb**.

Trying to calculate used storage with next query (see output below):

`SELECT  table_schema, SUM(data_length + index_length + data_free)/1024/1024/1024 AS total_Gb, SUM(data_length)/1024/1024/1024 AS data_Gb, SUM(index_length)/1024/1024/1024 AS index_Gb, SUM(data_free)/1024/1024/1024 AS free_Gb, COUNT(*) AS tables  FROM  information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema ORDER BY 2 DESC;`

Since the total size of the database (including free_data for this database) is **13.6Gb**, I don't understand where the rest of the storage is missing (5-6Gb).

The main question is why FreeStorageSpace metric in CloudWatch shows only 10Gb free while I can see almost 15Gb free on MySQL?

````
| table_schema       | total_Gb        | data_Gb         | index_Gb       | free_Gb         | tables |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+--------+
| information_schema | 14.156433105469 |  0.000183105469 | 0.000000000000 | 14.156250000000 |     63 |
| main_database      | 13.608055360615 | 11.013053961098 | 1.915313899517 |  0.679687500000 |    373 |
| mysql              |  0.018694377504 |  0.008742786013 | 0.000185966492 |  0.009765625000 |     43 |
| sys                |  0.000015258789 |  0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 |  0.000000000000 |    101 |
| performance_schema |  0.000000000000 |  0.000000000000 | 0.000000000000 |  0.000000000000 |     87 |
+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+--------+```

Here is allocation for information_schema tables:

| table_schema       | table_name                                              | total_Gb       | data_Gb        | index_Gb       | free_Gb        | tables |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------+
| information_schema | PROCESSLIST                                             | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | EVENTS                                                  | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | PLUGINS                                                 | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | VIEWS                                                   | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | PARTITIONS                                              | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | RDS_EVENTS_THREADS_WAITS_CURRENT                        | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | RDS_PROCESSLIST                                         | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | PARAMETERS                                              | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | TRIGGERS                                                | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | COLUMNS                                                 | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | OPTIMIZER_TRACE                                         | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
| information_schema | ROUTINES                                                | 1.179702758789 | 0.000015258789 | 0.000000000000 | 1.179687500000 |      1 |
````

Comment: Operating system and other apps that AWS runs on your RDS also take space.

Comment: @Marcin but why MySQL report 14Gb of free_data on the information_schema database?

Answer (score 0):

With this query, you would have more details to identify table using the 14 G in information_schema.

SELECT  table_schema, table_name, SUM(data_length + index_length + data_free)/1024/1024/1024 AS total_Gb, SUM(data_length)/1024/1024/1024 AS data_Gb, SUM(index_length)/1024/1024/1024 AS index_Gb, SUM(data_free)/1024/1024/1024 AS free_Gb, COUNT(*) AS tables  FROM  information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema, table_name ORDER BY 3 DESC;

What is result of SELECT @@version; ?

Comment: Result of "select @@version;" - 5.7.33-log.

14Gb is free_data on information schema, it's split between its tables by 1.17Gb each.

I'm okay with this size the question is why FreeStorageSpace metrics reports only 10Gb instead of 14Gb?

And actually if those 10Gb will go down RDS will be terminated. So I'm trying to understand for what this space used.

Comment: Please ASK AWS since they are collecting your monthly fees.

Answer (score 0):

Run a similar query, but look at each table in your database.  You will probably find that each table has between 4M and 7M of "Data_free".  This is normal.  The database preallocates that space.

If you find a *table* that has more than 7MB free, then let's look more closely at it.

Also, do you have hundreds of tables?  Or lots of `PARTITIONs` in some tables?  Again, we can discuss the details once you have presented them.

**More**

I suspect that "Free Storage Space" refers to disk space in general, and has nothing to do with the database.  The SELECT refers to disk space allocated to the database, but not currently in use.  Those two quantities are mostly unrelated.

If you get a bigger disk (move to a different RDS offering), the disk amount will increase; the SELECT will not change.  If you add lots of rows to your database tables, the disk amount will decrease and the SELECT will show an increase in Data_length and Index_length, but Data_free will not change significantly and may go up or down.

Comment: Partition is not used. Sorry, probably my original question was not clear. The main question is why FreeStorageSpace metric in CloudWatch shows only 10Gb free while I can see almost 15Gb free on MySQL?

Comment: @Nomirimon - I think they are two different metrics.  See what I added.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone will dig up a similar problem.
The main reason for this space usage is Fragmentation.

Fragmentation means that the physical ordering of the index pages on the disk is not close to the index ordering of the records on the pages, or that there are many unused pages in the 64-page blocks that were allocated to the index.

If you will run the next two queries

```
SELECT table_schema, ROUND(SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024/1024,2) "size in GB" FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 DESC; 

SELECT file_name, tablespace_name, ((total_extents * extent_size)/1024/1024/1024) as size_Gb from information_schema.files WHERE total_extents <> 0 order by size_Gb DESC;
```

the results will be completely different and it will allow you to calculate % of fragmentation. Looks like the only way to resolve this is described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html.